# How do I serve different Ktor modules on different ports?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I've got an application that I'm trying to serve different modules (with different application/routings) on different ports.

This is so that I can then restrict port access by different subnets.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Alternatively, I can run multiple ktor servers within my application, but was recommended against it due to how ktor optimizes to run in the JVM.

Would love some guidance on this, thanks!

Comment: I believe port access restriction should be done on OS level (for Linux see [nftables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nftables))